# converting negative values to rgb

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors

I want color my grid with values in my Matrix. the size of my matrix is 180*90 and there are different values such as 0, positive numbers and some negative numbers such as -45. 
My question is how can i convert negative numbers to values which is acceptable for d3.color for coloring my grid?

Comment: is there a range on your numbers? e.g., from -100 to 600

Comment: The general answer is *"use a scale"*. The precise answer depends on how do you want to map your values to the colours... therefore, please edit your question, since it currently lacks information. See [ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: if you do have a defined range you could take a look on `map` function from p5.js
[here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/map) is the documentation on the method and [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/0.8.0/src/math/calculation.js#L422) you can find the method implementation

Comment: congrats on asking 33,333th d3 question

Comment: in fact my file is a huge file, and for understand about range of my numbers i must check

Comment: by the way, your points were helpful for me and gave me this idea that i try find a range for my numbers and after that try to use scale.